# How to have different page numbering types in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word

Trying to figure out how to get two different page numbering styles into the same document in MS Word.

The section highlighted in yellow is what I am trying to replicate.

As you can see, there are pages that are using Roman numerals, and pages using Indo-Arabic numbers.

Currently using MS word 2013.

[image]

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  See Numbering Front Matter by Suzanne Barnhill http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial pages, set the page numbers as roman numerals.
When you want the actual numbers to start, go to:
Page Layout > Breaks > Section Breaks (Next Page)
Then in the new section, set your page numbering to 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 0):

Page numbering is easy with "page breaking" and "format page number" under the "page number" option.

Firstly, break your document by using page layout -> breaks -> new page. Then, insert page numbers by the insert -> page numbers. Now you have page numbers. To change the format of the page numbers in different sections, Select the first-page number of any section and change the format of the page numbers by selecting "format page number" option under the insert -> page number.

Click [here](https://frontendguider.com/127/how-to-add-different-page-numbers-for-different-sections-in-ms-word/) for more information.